# Setting the Display Name with Asterisk MessageSend

Tags: asterisk

I am setting up Asterisk to connect a few phones / sip-devices on my LAN.

I am able to send messages to each device via the [MessageSend()](https://docs.asterisk.org/Asterisk_18_Documentation/API_Documentation/Dialplan_Applications/MessageSend/) application in the extensions.conf file :

```
[...]
same => n,Set(MESSAGE(from)=JohnDoe) ; the exact display name I want to set, without IP address
same => n,MessageSend(pjsip:PJSIP/destendpoint@destaor)
[...]
```

My issue: I would like that the phone receiving the message displays the sender's name as *exactly* "JohnDoe".

However, the configuration above shows up in the destination-phone as "JohnDoe@AsteriskServerIP" (e.g. "JohnDoe@192.168.123.123"). And I do not want the IP to be included in the display name.

I have tried a few more things : e.g. while `Set(MESSAGE(from)=JohnDoe@SomeArbitraryIP)`, e.g. `Set(MESSAGE(from)=JohnDoe@192.168.456.456)` would show as "JohnDoe@192.168.456.456" on the receiving phone, `Set(MESSAGE(from)=JohnDoe@)` (with no IP at all after the '@'), would default back to the default "JohnDoe@AsteriskServerIP" ("JohnDoe@192.168.123.123").

My question : what should I do to have a display name without an IP address attached?